# Using superstrength to save falling people

Tags: internal-consistency, super-powers

In a world where superpowers exist, two office workers are trapped on the Nth floor of a burning skyscraper.

Superstrong Sam is 100 times as strong as a regular mortal. That means his muscles can exert 100 times the force that would normally be expected, and his bones and connecting tissues can withstand 100 times the force.

That means he can jump out the window no problem. Ignoring air resistance, he could fall 50 floors and only feel the impact as hard as a regular mortal falling 0.5 floors. Taking air resistance into account, even if the skyscraper is tall enough to reach terminal velocity, he would feel the impact as if it were only sqrt(1/100) = 1/10 of terminal velocity.

Sam's friend, Normal Norman, has no superpowers. If he jumps from a window more than a few floors up, he's going to go splat.

Is there anything Sam can do to save his friend?

If he also had the power of flight, he could do something. It would be more complex than shown in the Superman comics. You would need to accelerate downward to match velocity, grab the person, then decelerate.

But in this case, Sam cannot fly.

He could grab Norman, then jump. But is the sudden stop at the end, going to be any less lethal to Norman if he is being held by Sam than if he just hit the ground by himself?

He could jump, land, then shout "Jump, I'll catch you!" but is Norman going to survive hitting Sam, any better than he would survive hitting pavement?

Is there something else he could do that I am missing?

Comment: Are there any buildings nearby that are not burning?  The acceleration to jump to the next building over might be less stress on Normal Norman's body than the sudden stop of an X-story fall...

Comment: I don't quite get how this question got closed for being too story based. I'd expect at least some comments asking for clearification whether this is about saving Norman from this particular burning skyscraper (which would indeed be too story based) or if this is about the ability to save a non-super person from being killed due to a long fall, before the question is closed. Would clarification that this is not about these specific persons in this exact situation (Norman and Sam in a burning building) be enough to reopen the question?

Comment: @ooak Agreed. I think it was closed on a hasty reading. It's ultimately a question of biology and physics. Superhero feats are WAY more complex than the comics bother with, but it seems like an interesting question.

Comment: Why wouldn't they both go into the fire shielded core of the building and walk down the stairs? The fire shield core that is there by regulations to handle the emergency as described.

Comment: Why would being 100 times stronger than the average human *mean* that falling down 50 floors is effectively like falling down 0.5 floors? I can't imagine that math being so linearly related: how exactly did you calculate that?

Comment: @Joachim Energy equals force multiplied by distance. Same gravity, one hundred times the height, means one hundred times the kinetic energy. Same size body, same stopping distance, means one hundred times the force of impact.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor Well, it's a question about biology and physics, not building safety. I'm really using the skyscraper as an example, in the hope of being able to apply results to other situations like falling off cliffs, out of airplanes etc.

Comment: Is there any way Sam could just strap Norman on his back and climb out instead? If his grip is 100 times stronger too, he may be able to climb easier than a normal human, so long as the outside surface isn't too flat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is "It depends from how high up Norman is falling - but maybe?"

If Sam catches Norman - he has the space of let's say 1.8 metres to dissipate all of Normans kinetic energy.

If Norman is falling at 120kph (34 m/s), he will cover the last 1.8 metres in his fall at 0.05s.

Decelerating from that speed in that time (yes, yes, I know that as you decelerate, the time increases - using easy maths) - thats 64 G worth of acceleration. Enough to cause serious injury and even Death...

*but not unsurvivable* - some Race car accidents have hit peak G loads IIRC of almost 200G.

Now, if Sam can increase the time by 4, (from 0.05 - to 0.2 s) - that's 17G - still gonna hurt, but much more likely to survive.

So - theoretically, Sam reaches up as high as he can - Arms outstretched tall - he's got a reach of about 60cm - so that's 2.4 Metres of distance. The moment Normans toes touch Sams hands, he starts to decelerate him, but also, he starts changing his direction from straight down, to an angle - converting some of his momentum away at an angle.

This change in direction increases the distance Sam has to decelerate Norman - which increases the time he has, which decreases the G-Forces felt - which ultimately decreases the injuries.

So - TL;DR - With perfect technique and timing, it's possible that Norman is wounded but otherwise alive.

Comment: at least initially, the force would be concentrated to only the area of his hands, later his arms though. sounds painful for NN. he'd probably snap his neck.

Comment: Non-survivable.  While I agree the deceleration is within the range that could possibly be survived the support is not--surviving that with fully body support is very different than surviving it with two arms as the sole support.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - yes, but Sam has super-human strength, so we are allowed to assume that his two super-strength arms have more support than the average full body.

Comment: @TheDemonLord No.  He appears normal, his arms can provide no more support than normal arms.  They can provide far more force, but they can't increase the contact area.

Answer (score 6):

Sam can

1. Grab many metallic objects, preferably as long and thin as possible.  (Metal tubes used in chairs, perhaps)
2. tear them apart as necessary
3. bend them into shape so they hook into each other
4. Lower Norman using the chain he has made.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not feeling very mathy, but I'd guess the best option is for Sam to tell Norman to jump out and fall with his back toward the ground, on Sam's signal. Sam then jumps down and gives the signal. Using super intuition, Sam times his  jump such that he is near the apex when catching Norman, reducing Norman's downward velocity but not enough to severely injure him. Sam should cradle Norman's head and neck with his right arm and his lower back with his left. Sam needs to make sure he lands upright and falls into a squat, reducing the impulse felt by Norman as he slows down over a slightly longer period  .

Answer (score 2):

If there isn't fire venting out all sides of the building, climb down.

Sam breaks the window, Norman gets on his back and holds on. If they're in a building with an irregular surface where he can get a grip, Sam climbs down to an uninvolved floor, boots in a window, and they go looking for stairs.

Answer (score 2):

Sam grabs Norman and jumps out the window.

As they are approaching the ground, Sam throws Norman upwards with enough force to offset the majority of Norman's downward velocity (Sam's increases, but he can take it).  Sam can then carefully catch Norman to absorb as much of the remaining momentum as possible.

Comment: Same problem, the throw is even more lethal than a catch would be.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - there's no reason it has to be.  The throw can be much less abrupt than the catch would be, because a) it can take place over a longer interval, and b) he doesn't have to offset _all_ the velocity, just make the catch more survivable.

Comment: @jdunlop The basic problem is the distance he has available for the action.  That is severely limited (I would say 1 meter at most) and that imposes huge accelerations.  Throw and catch doubles this distance but that's still nowhere near enough to survive that acceleration given the lack of support.  It might be survivable with a custom fit acceleration cradle like on the Soyuz but he doesn't have one available.

Answer (score 1):

Frameshift:

There's no way Sam can arrest Norman's fall without inflicting lethal force on him in the process.  Therefore, don't fall.

Sam finds some strong pieces of metal, drives them into the wall as stakes to support climbing down.  If the wall isn't strong enough to support that Sam instead tears it away and grabs onto whatever is actually holding the building up.  While it would be possible for the wall to be made of something strong enough Sam can't drive anything into it few buildings are actually made that way.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... if Norman is not falling already then Sam can just hoist him up on his shoulders, tell him to hold on tight and climb down the walls. His superstrength will make the climb trivial and he likely can create grips by simply breaking hard to climb surfaces. He can also do this not for the entire height of the building but simpy climb past the fire and then they can walk down the stairs normally.

If there is a slope on the building somewhere, they can slide down even if it is very steep and Sam can use his strength to slow down the slide to acceptable levels and prevent them from falling off the slope. Probably can be done down some vertical walls too.

Sam can also break floors inside the building repeatedly and therefore create a series of relatively save points for Normann to jump down and get past the fire. Unless there is a completely burning floor, this can also be a viable escape strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Sam jumps up to Norman and cradles him in one arm. With the other hand he claws his super-fingers into the stone wall and slides down like a cat would slide down a normal wall. This leave a big rut down the wall.

Answer (score 0):

## Just fly down

A random person can generate 100J with a punch, a professional 400J. A 120 kilo duo moving at 10m/s has 6000J of energy. You can easily flap your arms twice a second, so even if you're untrained you can generate 20000J of energy with 100* human strength. Just flap your arms and you should be able to fly down just fine, or slow your fall a lot. If you have any large objects with a lot of surface area like posters take those to act as makeshift wings.

Comment: Punching and flapping do not produce the same amount of force. Further, you can't apply an arbitrarily high amount of force to the atmosphere by flapping your arms up and down twice a second but being super strong. F = MA, to apply more force your arms need to move faster. Also also, I imagine you mean newtons rather than joules

Comment: I corrected the unit error, and yes, you need to move your arms fast. Also, you're producing so much energy that you can probably easily manage it even if it's a bit less efficient than punching. You can make it more efficient as I said with makeshift wings to move more mass.